# Excel Spreadsheet search and replace

Tags: excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with 100s of 1000s of rows with the following values for software version numbers

11.2.4.5

8.4.1.1

8.0.0.1

2

4

1

null

unknown

which i want to change to

11.X

8.X

2.X

4.X

1.X

version unknown

version unknown

is this possible, could a formula be integrated into the spreadsheet or a button for the user to click and choose the column/row range

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: please tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest combining direct extraction of the numeric values with a lookup table (contents to be chosen by you) for the text ones:

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,F:G,2,FALSE),LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))&"X"),A1&".X")`

This attempts a lookup in F:G for text values and if not found defaults to searching for full stops and in turn if not found just adds `.X`.

Assumes your data is in ColumnA.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your data next to the Original Version Number. Put this into a cell at the top of the new column, changing the (C3) reference to your first cell reference:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".",C3)),CONCATENATE(LEFT(C3,(FIND(".",C3))),"X"),IF(ISNUMBER(C3),CONCATENATE(C3,".X"),"Version Unknown"))
```

Copy down.